# What is the best method to stream constant data using Axios + JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, axios

First post! Doing some self learning, so I'm quite new to everything. I'm doing some calculations starting with a beginning value that repeat infinitely and incrementing the value each time. The calculation result is added to the back of a simple string. So far i've been able to push up the 1000 counter manually until the calculation + submission time exceeds the server open window. Id like to actually constantly stream to an API endpoint (until the endpoint closes the connection) to see how much data I'm able to send as quick as possible. The data is in the 'submit' string. Does anyone know if Axios can achieve this with Node.js?

```
function packetSubmit(submitData) {
    let submitConfig = {
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://TestAPI/submit',
        headers: {'Cookie': 'id=MYID'},
        maxBodyLength: Infinity,
        data : submitData
    };
    
    axios(submitConfig)
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}

let startConfig = {
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://TestAPI/start',
    headers: {'Cookie': 'id=MYID'}
};

axios(startConfig)
.then((response) => {
    startValue = (JSON.stringify(response.data)).replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
    let firstStartValue = (parseInt(startValue));
    while (counter <= 1000) {
        submit += Calc(firstStartValue)
        ++firstStartValue;
        ++counter;
    }
    packetSubmit(submit);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
})
```

Comment: What's the problem? If you want to stream data look at WebSockets

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov Thanks for this. No problem, I'm just quite new and not sure what the best method was. Is it possible to stream data from a WebSocket client to the destination API? I don't have access to editing anything on the endpoint